# How do you calculate the growth rate when there is a population increase?

Tags: statistics, ratio

I have a population of let's say 5000
in this population, I have 10 sick people
and every 5 days the number of sick people grow by 180%.

Let's say now I have introduced another 3000 people to my population at the end of the first 5th day period.

How many sick people will I have in the next 5 days?

I am trying to understand how to include the population growth in this kind of increase.

Also, what is the area of maths that is concerned with this sort of topic, please?

Comment: The problem definition does not suppose any link between the doubling time of the sick population and the size of the population itself, so why do you expect there is one? It seems unlikely that the 10 original sick people would interact with all 5000 individuals within 5 days, so adding more people they never interact with doesn't seem like it should have any effect. A sick person may interact with 100 people and infect 1.8 of them on average - doubling the size of the population doesn't imply sick people now interact with 200 others and infect 3.6 of them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.